# Проблема с потоком PyQt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qt-designer, qthread

Никак не получается подвязать многопоточность к одной из моих функций в программе.

Программа просто не реагирует на нажатие кнопки. Пытался изменить значение `change_value`  на значение переменной `lineEdit_2` - тот же самый результат.

```
import urllib.request
import time
import json
import socket
import requests, sys
import ipaddress

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


# Сигнал
class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    upd = pyqtSignal(int)


    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass,self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        mas = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 42, 43, 53, 67, 69, 80, 110, 115, 123, 137, 138, 139, 143, 161, 179, 443, 445,
               514, 515,
               993, 995]
        host = self.lineEdit_2.emit(int)
        try:
            ipaddress.ip_network(host)
            for port in mas:
                s = socket.socket()
                s.settimeout(1)
                try:
                    s.connect((host, port))
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    per2 = (str(port) + ' port open!')

                    a = self.textEdit_5.emit(per2)
                    print(per2)
                except socket.error:
                    per3 = (str(port) + ' port locked!')
                    b = self.textEdit_5.emit(per3)
        except ValueError:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'Invalid IP!')


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    lineEdit_2: QLineEdit

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1321, 934)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"  background-color:silver\n"
"}")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:black")
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.wh1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 39, 181, 41))
        self.wh1.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh1.setText("")
        self.wh1.setObjectName("wh1")
        self.wh2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 181, 31))
        self.wh2.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh2.setText("")
        self.wh2.setObjectName("wh2")
        self.wh3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 181, 61))
        self.wh3.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh3.setText("")
        self.wh3.setObjectName("wh3")
        self.wh4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 181, 51))
        self.wh4.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh4.setText("")
        self.wh4.setObjectName("wh4")
        self.wh5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 181, 61))
        self.wh5.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh5.setText("")
        self.wh5.setObjectName("wh5")
        self.wh6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 160, 181, 51))
        self.wh6.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh6.setText("")
        self.wh6.setObjectName("wh6")
        self.wh7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 180, 421, 61))
        self.wh7.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh7.setText("")
        self.wh7.setObjectName("wh7")
        self.wh8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 250, 261, 81))
        self.wh8.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh8.setText("")
        self.wh8.setObjectName("wh8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setToolTipDuration(-7)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color:black;")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1321, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def showMessageBox(self,title,messege):
        msgBox = QtGui.QMessegeBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QtGui.QMessegeBox.Warning)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle(title)
        msgBox.setText(messege)
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.exce_()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))

    ## Ниже функция





class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent = None)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.__init__())

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

            self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
            self.threadclass.start()
            self.threadclass.a.connect(self.lineEdit_2.emit)
            self.threadclass.b.connect(self.textEdit_5.emit)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(Интерфейс)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем вы изменяете модуль созданный в `Qt Designer` ? Что такое `import self`,  Что такое `self.self.change_value.connect(self.run)` ? Где вы вызываете метод `def stp(self):` ? Метод `run` должен находится в `class mythread(QThread):` и то что в нем выполняется в дополнительном потоке. Если вы собираетесь передавать какие-то данные из потока, то где-то в методе `run` должно быть `self.change_value.emit(<int>)` ...

Comment: НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.

Comment: Работе с потоками посвящено много постов, попробуйте почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: @S.Nick Cпасибо за ответ!С самим созданием потоком я разобрался.Но я не понял,как нормально разбить функцию по сигналам.К примеру мне надо взять входные точки взятия текста?Или взять полностью всю функцию? –

Comment: @S.Nick Как я понял,emit(<int>) берет значение с переменной?Или оно просто означает её тип? – justdeveloper1 20 минут назад

Comment: вы же для чего-то создали сигнал `change_value = pyqtSignal(int)`? я так понимаю, что вы собираетесь передавать из потока какие-то данные, тип которых `int`.  Т.е. например в потоке есть переменная, например назовем ее `value` и этой переменной вы присваиваете какое-то значение, например `12` (`value = 12`). Тогда чтобы передать это значение из дополнительного потока в основной, вы должны в дополнительном потоке испустить сигнал `self.change_value.emit(value)`

Comment: @S.Nick Приветствую вновь!У меня опять к вам вопрос.Как мне использовать параметр 'emit' для окна?Я выразил у `self.textEdit_5.emit`' в две перменные `a` и `b` , но мне это ничего не дало.На всякий случай,я апдейтнул код выше

Comment: нет, вы не правильно делаете. Попробую глянуть на ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
#import os
#import urllib.request
#import time
#import json
import socket
#import requests
import ipaddress
#from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
#    upd = pyqtSignal(int)
    mySignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    
#                      vvvv
    def __init__(self, host, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass,self).__init__(parent)
        self.host = host                                               #+++

    def run(self):
        mas = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 42, 43, 53, 67, 69, 80, 110, 115, 123, 137, 138, 139, 143, 161, 179, 443, 445,
               514, 515,
               993, 995]
#        host = self.lineEdit_2.emit(int)
        
        try:
            ipaddress.ip_network(self.host)                           # self.host
            for port in mas:
                s = socket.socket()
                s.settimeout(1)
                try:
                    s.connect((self.host, port))
#                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    self.msleep(1500)
                    per2 = f'{port} <- port open!'
#                    self.textEdit_5.emit(per2)
                    self.mySignal.emit(per2)
#                    print(per2)
                except socket.error:
                    per3 = (str(port) + ' port locked!')
#                    self.textEdit_5.emit(per3)
                    self.mySignal.emit(per3)
        except ValueError:
#            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'Invalid IP!')
            self.mySignal.emit('Error! --->>> Invalid IP!')


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
# ?   lineEdit_2: QLineEdit
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1321, 934)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"  background-color:silver\n"
"}")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:black")
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.wh1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 39, 181, 41))
        self.wh1.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh1.setText("")
        self.wh1.setObjectName("wh1")
        self.wh2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 181, 31))
        self.wh2.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh2.setText("")
        self.wh2.setObjectName("wh2")
        self.wh3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 181, 61))
        self.wh3.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh3.setText("")
        self.wh3.setObjectName("wh3")
        self.wh4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 181, 51))
        self.wh4.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh4.setText("")
        self.wh4.setObjectName("wh4")
        self.wh5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 181, 61))
        self.wh5.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh5.setText("")
        self.wh5.setObjectName("wh5")
        self.wh6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 160, 181, 51))
        self.wh6.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh6.setText("")
        self.wh6.setObjectName("wh6")
        self.wh7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 180, 421, 61))
        self.wh7.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh7.setText("")
        self.wh7.setObjectName("wh7")
        self.wh8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 250, 261, 81))
        self.wh8.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh8.setText("")
        self.wh8.setObjectName("wh8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)       
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setToolTipDuration(-7)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color:black;")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1321, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch 333"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))

       
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit_2.setText('78.154.187.198')
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.onPunch)   

    def onPunch(self):
        host = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass(host, self)
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.threadclass.mySignal.connect(self.msg_thread)
        self.threadclass.finished.connect(self.msg_thread_finished)
        

    def msg_thread(self, text):
        self.textEdit_5.append(text)
        
    def msg_thread_finished(self):
        self.textEdit_5.append(' -- msg_thread_finished --')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @justdeveloper1 что не так?

Comment: @justdeveloper1 если мои ответы вас учат чему-то новому, не забывайте отмечать их и как полезный.

Comment: Благодарю!Я наконец-то понял как это работает!Надеюсь,что у меня больше не появятся вопросы на эту тему :)

Comment: @justdeveloper1 никогда не говорите никогда